# ASP.NET MVC4 creating new Model which has navigation attributes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to ASP.NET and I'm trying to achieve the following thing:

I'm developing using MVC4 and code-first approach to EF, I have the following Model:

```
public class Booking {
  // Lot of standard int/string attributes

  // And a navigation attribute
  public virtual Teaching teaching {get;set;}
}
```

Teaching is another model which is pretty basic. I bootstrapped my database using an initializer and everything is fine, EF created me my SQL structure and added automatically Teaching_Id to the Booking table. My model is also correctly populated (lazy loading I guess) and I can print model.Teaching.name for instance in my Index view.

I'm now looking to make a create form to add new Bookings to my database, and I want the user to be able to choose a teaching from a List. I managed to achieve this so far, my view is pretty standard (auto generated):

```
 <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BookingDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BookingDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BookingDate)
    </div>
```

and so far for simple attributes. I made this for the select list

In my controller :

```
var id = (int)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
ViewBag.listTeachings = db.Teachings.Where(x => x.Teacher.UserId == id).ToList();
```

In my view (inside the form)

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Teaching.Id, new SelectList(ViewBag.listTeachings, "Id", "Id"))
```

(for testing purpose I'm priting the Id in the drop down list)

When I POST my form, everything is OK (no model state error) but nothing is added in the db. In my form POST content I have a Teachings.Id entry. I also tried to use DropDownListFor model => model.Teaching instead of model.Teaching.Id but an Teaching entry is passed to PostData and I guess he doesn't know how to convert pure int to an object.

Any help is appreciated, thank you for reading and thanks by advance!

Comment: Have you declared your database Context Object in the  Controller and used that Object to save data through that DB Context Object to the Database in **[HttpPost]** Action Controller?

Comment: Sure, my HttpPost Controller is doing a standard .Add(object) and .SaveContext()

Comment: Can you please show your code ?

Comment: if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Bookings.Add(model);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

Comment: Ok it seems that VS wasn't refreshing correctly my tables. Actually it is inserting; but the Teaching_Id inserted is false (he is generating a new one alone). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so my model passed in the Create() function was effectively containing the Teaching.Id, but it seems that EF was not able to map it to the good foreign key or whatever.

I made it working by using this solution in the POST Create controller :

```
 model.Teaching = teachingRepo.Find(model.Teaching.Id);
```

Noting that this doesn't work :

```
 model.Teaching = new Teaching() { Id = model.Teaching.Id }
```

(if anyone has an explanation about this I'm not against it)